# Drawer Item Order (React Native)

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

this may be a really stupid question but I really haven't been able to find anything about this. What I am currently trying to do, is to change the order of the items in my List. The first two navigate to screens and the last 3 are custom drawer items. What I want to achieve is to move the "About" Item towards the bottom of the Drawer and add some margin between the "Belval Navigator" and the remaining 3 Items.

In the end it should look like this ->

Belval Navigator

-

Art

Culture

Science

### -

- 

About

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import Navigation from '../config/Navigation';
import About from '../screens/AboutScreen';

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem label="Art" onPress={() => alert('Toggle Art')} />
      <DrawerItem label="Culture" onPress={() => alert('Toggle Culture')} />
      <DrawerItem label="Science" onPress={() => alert('Toggle Science')} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

export default function Drawer() {
  return (
    <DrawerNavigator.Navigator
      drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <DrawerNavigator.Screen
        name="Belval Navigator"
        component={Navigation}
        options={() => ({
          swipeEnabled: false,
          drawerLabel: 'Belval Navigator',
        })}
      />
      <DrawerNavigator.Screen
        name="About"
        component={About}
        options={{swipeEnabled: true}}
      />
    </DrawerNavigator.Navigator>
  );
}
```

[image: Current Order]

Answer (score 3):

Try to hide your screens in **drawerNavigator** and then add them to **CustomDrawerContent**:

First hide your screens by adding the following property to the screens:

```
      options={{ 
  drawerItemStyle: {
    height: 0
}}}
/>
```

Then in your CustomDrawerContent add the screens as a drawerItem and navigate to them using navigation.navigate:

```
 <DrawerItem label="Belval Navigator"  onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('Navigation')}}   />
```

Now just reorder the drawerItems in CustomDrawerContent according to the order you desire.